# Do two isomorphic finite field extensions have the same dimension?

Tags: vector-spaces, field-theory, extension-field

If $E = F(u_1, \cdots u_n) \cong \bar{E} = F(v_1, \cdots v_m)$ then do the two extensions necessarily have the same dimension over $F$?

Comment: Why wouldn't they? :)

Comment: I don't know, I can't think of any reason they wouldn't

Comment: I have a proof for the case when $F$ is finite. The infinite case is true too, I am thinking of a proof.

Comment: Isomorphic as what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Claim that if $E$ is a field extension over $F$ and $\sigma$ is a homomorphism from $E$ into $E'$, then $[E^{\sigma}:F^{\sigma}]=[E:F]$. You can prove this by showing that $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots ,v_n\}\text{ is a basis of E over F}\iff\{\sigma(v_1),\sigma(v_2),\ldots ,\sigma(v_n)\}\text{ is a basis of }$ $E^{\sigma}$ over $F^{\sigma} $

Now what happens in the case when $\sigma$ is an isomorphism of $E$ onto $E'$ and fixes $F$?

Comment: By $E^{\sigma}$ do you mean the image of $E$ in $E'$?

Comment: Yes. I wrote a general result. So, in this scenario, the image of $E$ in $E'$ would be.....?

Comment: $E'$, if you mean my scenario with the isomorphism. Thank you, I'll give it a go later tonight